# Docker & PM2: String based CMD with environment variables

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, pm2

I'm currently using the [shell](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)-form of `CMD` in Docker for launching my node app:

```
CMD /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/trifid --config $TRIFID_CONFIG
```

The env-var `TRIFID_CONFIG`is set to a default in the `Dockerfile`:

```
ENV TRIFID_CONFIG config.customer.json
```

This makes it easy to pass another config file for dev-environments for example.

Now I try to switch this to [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/docker-pm2-nodejs/) for production. However it looks like all PM2 samples are using the "exec" form which from what I understood does not evaluate ENV-vars. I tried the shell-form with PM2:

```
CMD pm2-docker /usr/src/app/node_modules/trifid/server.js --config $TRIFID_CONFIG
```

But it looks like the variable is not evaluated like this, it fails back to default on execution.

What would be the proper way to handle this with PM2 inside a Docker image?

Comment: you should better use a process file to configure this http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/

Comment: ok will check it out and adjust my answer when I get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a discussion on [Github](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2661) and meanwhile figured it out:

```
CMD pm2-docker /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/trifid -- --config $TRIFID_CONFIG
```

So the trick is to use `--` after the command and the rest will be passed as argument. If I use the shell form env-vars do seem to get evaluated properly.